# ANDROID radiogroup not saving oncheckedchangeListener

Tags: android, radio-group

**code fragment of what I've tried:**

```
    String servng, mealname, strDate;

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btFoodVegetableSave:
        mealname = selected;
        String serving  = calories.getText().toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(serving.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

        servng = String.valueOf(i);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        strDate = sdf.format(new Date());

        if ( ( mealname.isEmpty() || servng.isEmpty() ) ){

            // call for custom toast
            viewErrorToast();
        }

        else {

        boolean didItWork = true;

        try{

            rgMeal.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch( checkedId ){
                    case R.id.rbBreakfast:
                        BreakFastLog bfLog = new BreakFastLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        bfLog.open();
                        bfLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        bfLog.close();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbMorningSnack:
                        MorningSnackLog msLog = new MorningSnackLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        msLog.open();
                        msLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        msLog.close();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbLunch:
                        LunchLog lunchLog = new LunchLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        lunchLog.open();
                        lunchLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        lunchLog.close();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbAfternoonSnack:
                        AfternoonSnackLog asLog = new AfternoonSnackLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        asLog.open();
                        asLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        asLog.close();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbDinner:
                        DinnerLog dinnerLog = new DinnerLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        dinnerLog.open();
                        dinnerLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        dinnerLog.close();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbEveningSnack:
                        EveningSnackLog esLog = new EveningSnackLog(Bread_Dark.this);
                        esLog.open();
                        esLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                        esLog.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });


            }
            catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
                viewErrorToast();
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
                    viewBMRSavedToast();
                }

            }
        } // end of if else statement
        break;
```

**the xml layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="481dp"
android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/tabs_menu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFoodVegetable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cabbage"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:inputType="number" >


    <requestFocus android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</EditText>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spFoodVegetable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:prompt="@string/white_bread_prompt" />


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btFoodVegetableCalories"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/done"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/darkgreen"
    android:textSize="@dimen/padding_extralarge"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_meal_selected" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="@string/choosemeal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioGroup
          android:paddingLeft="10dp"
          android:id="@+id/rgSelectMeal"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical" >



<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbBreakfast"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/breakfast"
    android:checked="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbMorningSnack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/morningsnack" />


   <RadioButton
       android:id="@+id/rbLunch"
       android:layout_width="128dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/lunch" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbAfternoonSnack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/afternoonsnack" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbDinner"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dinner" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rbEveningSnack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/eveningsnack" />


</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btFoodVegetableSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/save24"
    android:background="@drawable/nutrition_button_gradiant"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user would check from radio group and click the save button, it goes to my FINALLY statement:

```
 finally{
            if (didItWork){
                viewBMRSavedToast();
            }
```

But when i would check the summary (list of records inserted/saved to the database), it's not being saved :( what's wrong with my handling of radiogroup here?

Comment: Are you telling you radiogroup to listen to the overridden onclick event? radiogroups.setonlicklistener(this);

Comment: yes, this is what i tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the user to click on a radio button and then to create a new BreakFastLog when the user presses "Save". What you're currently doing is making a checkChangedListener for the radiogroup *after* the "Save" button has been clicked. This will cause the chain of events to happen in inverse order from what you want (what you're seeing). In order for the user to select a radiobutton and then click "save" you only need to retrieve the currently checked radiobutton within the radiogroup, not make a checkChangedListener. This can be done by:

```
   int checkedId = rgMeal.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
   switch( checkedId ){
      case R.id.rbBreakfast:
          BreakFastLog bfLog = new BreakFastLog(Bread_Dark.this);
          bfLog.open();
          bfLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
          bfLog.close();
          break;
      case R.id.rbMorningSnack:
          MorningSnackLog msLog = new MorningSnackLog(Bread_Dark.this);
          msLog.open();
          msLog.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   .
     }
```

`